# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 in recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote following recursive function it is throwing an exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2. It is working for small structure but while I am trying to give a part number which is having large structure exception is coming.

I call the function using 
`recursionTest(1, stub, partNo, list);`

Code is:

```
public static void recursionTest(int level, SoapBindingStub stub, 
         String partNumber, List<Part> list) throws RemoteException {

    String children = (String) stub.getPartDelegate(partNumber);

    String[] parts = children.split(",");

    if(parts.length == 1)
        return;

    for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {

        String[] childDetail = parts[i].split(":");

        list.add(setPartAttributes(level, childDetail));

        recursionTest(level + 1, stub, childDetail[0], list);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant portion of your stacktrace

Comment: I am storing the information about part in one string which contains name number etc. So to split this attributes I used ' : ' in program. So while printing and storing this information I will need ' : ' to separate those attributes.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at com.task.controllers.PartRestController.setPartAttributes(PartRestController.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.task.controllers.PartRestController.recursionTest(PartRestController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.task.controllers.PartRestController.recursionTest(PartRestController.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.task.controllers.PartRestController.recursionTest(PartRestController.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.task.controllers.PartRestController.getParts(PartRestController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: so the problem is at `setPartAttributes(Pa‌​rtRestController.jav‌​a:66)` not with the code you have posted

Comment: So the error is not in the code you're showing but in the setPartAttributes method you're **calling** from the code shown!

Comment: 60 public static Part setPartAttributes(int level, String[] detail) {
61  
62  Part part = new Part();
63  part.setLevel(level);
64  part.setNumber(detail[0]);
65  part.setName(detail[1]);
66  part.setLineNumber(detail[2]);
67  part.setQuantity(detail[3]);
68  part.setReferenceDesignator(detail[4]);
69  part.setUnit(detail[5]);
70  
71  return part;  
72 }

Comment: Ok, with that context the "mark as duplicate" is actually justified... On line 66 you're accessing index 2 of `detail` and you get an exception telling you that index 2 is out of bounds. So you're `detail` array obviously does not have the 6 elements needed for this method to work, as `parts[i].split(":");` doesn't return 6 or more elements.